# A virtual machine has disappeared

Tags: azure, ip, virtual-machine

There was a virtual machine that could be connected to and there was an ip associated with this virtual machine. Now for some reason I can't connect to this virtual machine. This error comes out. I looked at the list of all virtual machines and didn't see any connected to this ip address. Could one of the employees have deleted it? Or what could have happened to it?

Comment: have you checked the activity logs of the resource group of this VM? Also if you are connecting to a dynamic Public IP, it is changing every time the VM reboots. So the VM might still be there with a different IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address assigned by Azure to a Virtual Machine is dynamic in default

Selecting dynamic allocation method for an IP address resource means the IP address is not allocated at the time of the resource creation. The public IP address is allocated when you associate the public IP address with a virtual machine. The IP address is released when you stop (or delete) the resource, the IP address can be assigned to a different resource. If the IP address is assigned to a different resource while resource A is stopped, when you restart resource A, a different IP address is assigned.

If the virtual machine is stopped or rebooted, the IP address will be deallocated from the Virtual Machine. So, you would not be able to connect to the Virtual Machine with the same IP address again.

You can also check the activity log of that Resource Group to check if the VM is deleted.

Comment: If a VM was been deleted, can it be restored?

Comment: I read that a backup copy of a virtual machine is stored for 14 days, and after 14 days it is permanently deleted?